# How to run a parallel function inside a serial one in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, parallelism-amdahl

Maybe this is really simple, but I am having a bit of a problem understanding this.

The challenge I have is to execute a child parallel function from inside a *mother* function. That *mother* function should run only once while waiting for the results of the child parallel function calls.

I wrote a little example which shows my dilemma.

```
import string
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

def jobToDoById(id):
    #do some other logic based on the ID given
    rand_str  = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for i in range(10))
    return [id, rand_str]


def childFunctionParallel(jobs):
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    num_cores = num_cores - 1

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(jobToDoById)(i) for i in jobs)
        return p

def childFunctionSerial(jobs):
    result = []
    for job in jobs:
        job_result = jobToDoById(job)
        result.append(job_result)
    return result



def motherFunction(countries_cities, doInParallel):
    result = []
    print("Start mainLogic")
    for country in countries_cities:
        city_list = countries_cities[country]
        if(doInParallel):
            cities_result = childFunctionParallel(city_list)
        else:
            cities_result = childFunctionSerial(city_list)
        result.append(cities_result)
        # ..... do some more logic

    # ..... do some more logic before returning
    print("End mainLogic")
    return result



print("Start Program")

countries_cities = {
    "United States" : ["Alabama", "Hawaii", "Mississippi", "Pennsylvania"],
    "United Kingdom" : ["Cambridge", "Coventry", "Gloucester", "Nottingham"],
    "France" : ["Marseille", "Paris", "Saint-Denis", "Nanterre", "Aubervilliers"],
    "Denmark" : ["Aarhus", "Slagelse", "Nykøbing F", "Rønne", "Odense"],
    "Australia" : ["Sydney", "Townsville", "Bendigo", "Bathurst", "Busselton"],
}
result_mother = motherFunction(countries_cities, doInParallel=True) # should be executed only once
print(result_mother) 
print("End Program")
```

If you toggle the `doInParallel` between `True` and `False` then you can see the problem. When running with the `childFunctionSerial()` the `motherFunction()` runs only once. But when we run with the `childFunctionParallel` then the `motherFunction()` is executed multiple times. Both give the same result but the problem I have is that `motherFunction()` should be executed only once.

Two questions:

**1.** How to restructure the program so that we executed the mother function once
 and from inside it, start a parallel job without running multiple instances of the same mother function?
 **2.** How can I pass a second parameter to the `jobToDoById()` besides the **`id`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ad 2: Put additional parameter(s) into a tuple & pass `( id, .., )`

This one was simple and is commonly used, so one can meet it in many examples.

```
def jobToDoById( aTupleOfPARAMs = ( -1, ) ): # jobToDoById(id):
    #                                        #    do some other logic based on the ID given
    if not type( aTupleOfPARAMs ) is tuple:  # FUSE PROTECTION
       return [-1, "call interface violated"]
    if aTupleOfPARAMs[0] == -1:              # FUSE PROTECTION
       return [-1, None]
    # .......................................# GO GET PROCESSED:
    rand_str  = ''.join( random.choice( string.ascii_lowercase
                                      + string.ascii_uppercase
                                      + string.digits
                                        )
                                  for i in range( 10 )
                         )
    return [id, rand_str]
```

The first question is a bit harder, yet way more interesting as system-design's [principal differences among **`[SERIAL]`**, "*just*"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** and true-**`[PARALLEL]`** system-scheduling policies of more than one processes](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5) are not always respected in popular media ( and sometimes even not in the Academia ).

---

### Ad 1: you might get surprised, this will never happen in current version

Your code mentioned **`joblib.Parallel`** and **`multiprocessing`** modules explicitly, yet documentation says:

> By default **`Parallel`** uses the Python **`multiprocessing`** module to **fork separate Python** worker **processes** to execute tasks concurrently on separate CPUs. This is a reasonable default for generic Python programs but it induces some overhead as the *input and output **data* need to be serialized in a queue** for communication with the worker processes.

There are two implications - your processing will **pay a dual**, [**`[TIME]`**-domain and **`[SPACE]`**-domain overhead costs, that may easily become **unacceptably huge OVERHEAD COSTS** ( and if one has already noticed also the words "***data***" and "***serialized***" in the citation above, the better ) - for details see re-formulated Amdahl's Law, as detailed in Section: Criticism et al](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) [parallelism-amdahl](/questions/tagged/parallelism-amdahl):

1. The **whole Python interpreter** including it's data and internal state is fully forked ( so you get as many copies as instructed, each running just one process-flow, which is made for the sake of not loosing performance on a GIL-round-robin fragmentation / Only-1-runs-All-Others-have-to-wait type of GIL-blocking / stepping present any 1+ processing-flow if made in threading-based pools etc. )
2. Besides all the complete Python interpreter + state re-instantiations that have to take place as noted above, also **ALL** **`<data-IN>`** + **`<data-OUT>`** are:

   ----------------------------MAIN-starts-to-escape-from-pure-[SERIAL]-processing--
   0:                        MAIN forks self
   [1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8337936/5)
   [2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)
   ...
   [n_jobs] - as many copies of self as requested
   -------------------------MAIN-can-continue-in-"just"-[CONCURRENT]-after:
   1st-Data-IN-SERialised-in-MAIN's-"**main**"

   - 2nd-Data-IN-QUEueed    in MAIN
   - 3rd-Data-IN-DEQueued              [ith_job]s
   - 4th-Data-IN-DESerialised          [ith_job]s
   - ( ...process operated the usefull [ith_job]s --planned... )
   - 5th-Data-OUT-SERialised           [ith_job]s
   - 6th-Data-OUT-QUEued               [ith_job]s
   - 7th-Data-OUT-DEQueued     in-MAIN
   - 8th-Data-OUT-DESerialised-in-MAIN's-"**main**"
     -------------------------------MAIN-can-continue-in-pure-[SERIAL]-processing-----

**which all together always costs non-negligible overhead-time** ( for equations and details, kindly **Ref.:** [overhead-strict re-formulation of **net-speedups achievable upon these add-on overhead costs**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3), best before diving into a refactoring, where your machine will pay way more than what it gets from attempts to ignore these principal and benchmarkable overhead costs )

For benchmarking these overhead costs, each separately, in microsecond measurements, tools are available ( yet not all Stack Overflow Members felt happy on doing quantitatively robust benchmarking of these ), just check other posts on [parallelism-amdahl](/questions/tagged/parallelism-amdahl) here on Stack Overflow.

The second principal limitation of `joblib.Parallel` implementation, that strucks, if not headbangs, into Amdahl's Law, is **a resources-real-availability-agnostic optimism**, while resources-state-aware scheduling is the thing that happens on each real-world system.

One may expect any high-degree of parallel code execution, but unless complex measures are taken on an end-to-end ( top-to-bottom ) system coverage, all processing goes but into a "just"-**`[CONCURRENT]`** schedule ( i.e. if resources permit ). This aspect is way extending the footprint of this post, and was just naively put into the scheme above, showing, that if CPU-cores ( and principally any other resource-class ) are not available, the concurrency
[**will never reach the levels of speedup**, that a resources-availability agnostic original Amdahl's Law was promising](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3).

```
----------------------------MAIN-starts-escape-from-processing---in-pure-[SERIAL]
  0:                        MAIN forks self                     -in-pure-[SERIAL]
                                 [1]                            -in-pure-[SERIAL]
                                 [2]                            -in-pure-[SERIAL]
                                 ...                            -in-pure-[SERIAL]
                                 [n_jobs] as many copies of self-in-pure-[SERIAL]
                                          as requested          -in-pure-[SERIAL]
  --------------------------MAIN-can-continue-in-"just"-[CONCURRENT]after[SERIAL]
+ 1st-Data-IN-SERialised-in-MAIN's-"__main__"  , job(2), .., job(n_jobs):[SERIAL]
+ 2nd-Data-IN-QEUueed    in MAIN for all job(1), job(2), .., job(n_jobs):[SERIAL]
+ 3rd-Data-IN-DEQueued              [ith_job]s:       "just"-[CONCURRENT]||X||X||
+ 4th-Data-IN-DESerialised          [ith_job]s:       "just"-[CONCURRENT]|X||X|||
+ ( ...process operated the usefull [ith_job]s-<The PAYLOAD>-planned... )||X|||X|
+ 5th-Data-OUT-SERialised           [ith_job]s:       "just"-[CONCURRENT]||||X|||
+ 6th-Data-OUT-QUEued               [ith_job]s:       "just"-[CONCURRENT]|X|X|X||
+ 7th-Data-OUT-DEQueued     in-MAIN <--l job(1), job(2), .., job(n_jobs):[SERIAL]
+ 8th-Data-OUT-DESerialised-in-MAIN's-"__main__" job(2), .., job(n_jobs):[SERIAL]
-------------------------------MAIN-can-continue-processing------in-pure-[SERIAL]
...                                                             -in-pure-[SERIAL]
```

Comment: Thank you @user3666197 for the answer :) i see now that this is not as simple as i thought...hmm, well in that case i will have to completely redesign the structure of my program so that it will accommodate parallel jobs that will not start inside the function but outside

Comment: Well, SIMPLICITY **is not the target** ( it can be as simple as a few SLOC-s, but at a cost ... of performance penalty... ), **The EFFICIENCY is ...** Next comes, if your computing requires many repetitions of some parts of the processing-graph, then a semi-persistent computing infrastructure, launched once and re-used many times, may fit better, than any re-instantiation(s) called ad-hoc many times. I use this for example in large-scale AI/ML computing, where overhead costs would be un-acceptably high both due to unwanted add-on latencies and astronomic data-size SER/ENQ/DEQ/DES costs ....